# Are static members implemented by making copies for each instance in C++?

Tags: c++, oop

I'm writing a C++ plotter in order to plot analog and digital signals. The plotter can plot one or more axes one above other. Each axe can be analog or digital. I.e.:

```
Analog axe 1 (with signals 1,2)
Analog axe 2 (with signals 1,3,6)
Digital axe 1  (with signals 1,2,3,8)
Analog axe 3 (with signals 3,8)
Digital axe 2 (with signals 3,4)
```

The axes have the same x axis (time) and are aligned.

The plotter can read some kind of data input such as CSV.

I want to read the input data once, store the analog data in a container and the digital data in another. Note that different axes can have common signals. Thus, I want avoid to have a container with repeated signals. I want to have a container with the full data, then plot the signals in the required axes.

I am implementing the following classes: (Incomplete code)

```cpp
class data_analog{
};

class data_digital{
};

class analog{
  static data_analog DataAnalog;
  double linewith;
  color linecolor;
  style linestyle;
public:
  trace_curve(); 
};

class digital{
  static data_digital DataDigital;
  color linecolor;
public:
  trace_digital();    
};

class axe{
  position p;
public:
  virtual void trace_all()=0;    
};

class axeAnalog: public axe{
  vector<analog> analogs;
public:
  void trace_all();    
};

class axeDigital: public axe{
  vector<digital>  digitals;
public:
  void trace_all();
};

class plot{
private:
  vector<axe> axes;
public:
  void print_axes();
};
```

I'm thinking to use static members in analog and digital classes, in order that all instances of these classes know the data.
I have little experience with OOP and C++. I don't know if this is the best solution for my problem. Additionally, I'm not sure if static members make a copy in memory or all objects point at the same memory address. If it makes a copy for each instance, it is not the best solution because copying large data is not a good idea.

Do you have any suggestion for this implementation?

Comment: SO is about specific, bite-sized, programming Q&A, not about design or code review related topics. Please [edit] your post to provide a [mcve].

Comment: The question was edited.

Comment: Small but subtle change (and admittedly the one I proposed.... ;-)  ). I have retracted my close-vote.

Answer (score 1):

No static members are not copies.
You can tell by the fact that if you change from one instance the change becomes visible from others. An example is an instance counter (incremented in ctor, decremented in dtor).

In spite of that I recommend against using static data members in most cases for the goal you describe. To be precise, only use static members if you really want ALL instances to share the same. Consider carefully whether that is applicable to your case.

In most cases I expect advantages from designing to allow separate groups of instances to share the same data member from among several.
For that I propose to separate the shared data into a dedicated class and all user instances get constructed with a reference to that instance of the shared data they are responsible for.